# Variable scope for if / else in Prolog

Tags: if-statement, scope, prolog

I'm trying to use the `->` operator in GNU Prolog, but I'm having some trouble with variable scope. Here's an example:

```
example(A) :-
  B = A,
  (B == 2 -> write(B), write(' is 2'), nl);
  (write(B), write(' is not 2'), nl).
```

In the Prolog console:

```
| ?- example(2).
2 is 2

true ? 

yes
| ?- example(3).
_282 is not 2

yes
```

When I query `example(2)`, `B == 2` succeeds and Prolog knows what the value of B is and thus prints out `2 is 2`.

On the other hand, when I query `example(3)`, `B == 2` fails and for some reason, Prolog does not know the value of B and therefore prints out some variable `_282`. I'm very confused as to why Prolog knows the value of B only when `B == 2` succeeds. Am I not using the `->` operator correctly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **put the semicolon (`;`) at the wrong place**. What you have written is syntactically equivalent to:

```
example(A) :-
    (   B=A,
        (   B==2
        ->  write(B),
        write(' is 2'),
        nl
        )
    ;   write(B),
        write(' is not 2'),
        nl
    ).
```

So there are two branches here: one where you set `B = A`, then check if `B == 2`, and if that is the case, you `write(B)` then `write(' is 2')` followed by a new line. In case `B` is not `2`, you also take that branch, but the calls in the if body (after the `->`) will not be called.

Next there is also a completely separate branch where you `write(B)` but notice that in that branch, we have not first passed through `B = A`, so for Prolog `B` is an ungrounded variable, next you `write(' is not 2')`. But what you thus see with the **`_282` is an ungrounded variable**.

You can fix it by putting the semicolon at the correct place:

```
example(A) :-
    B = A,
    (  B == 2
    -> (write(B), write(' is 2'), nl)
    ;  (write(B), write(' is not 2'), nl)
    ).
```

Or less verbose:

```
example(A) :-
    B = A,
    (  B == 2
    ->  write(B),
        write(' is 2'),
        nl
    ;   write(B),
        write(' is not 2'),
        nl
    )
).
```

Furthermore it is not clear to me why you construct a new variable in the first place. You can *work with `A` directly*:

```
example(A) :-
    (  A == 2
    ->  write(A),
        write(' is 2'),
        nl
    ;   write(A),
        write(' is not 2'),
        nl
    )
).
```

Comment: Thank you! To answer your last question, my actual code does a lot more work before the if / else statement; I just simplified everything for the sake of the question.